# How to evaluate expression in standard sql?

Tags: sql

I have an alphanumeric expression which I like to evaluate to true/false.
For example ('A' = 'B' or 10 > 5) should return true.
I am working with DB2 for i, so a standard sql would be required.
I tried

```
Select ('A' = 'B' or 10 > 5) from sysibm/sysdummy1
```

and

```
Select (('A' = 'B' or 10 > 5) = '1') from sysibm/sysdummy1
```

but the error says in the first case Token '(' required and in the second case Token '=' invalid.
How would you do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this please:

```
select case when 'A' ='B' or 10 > 5 then 1 else 0 end
```

Also maybe this post can help [Boolean Expressions in SQL Select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497522/boolean-expressions-in-sql-select-list)